# CoreData and NSManagedObject memory state

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios5

this a question I always wanted to ask.
When I am running an iOS application in Profiler looking for allocation issues, I found out that NSManagedObject stays in memory long after they have been used and displayed, and the UIViewController who recall has been deallocated. Of course when the UIViewController is allocated again, the number is not increasing, suggesting that there's no leak, and there's some kind of object reuse by CoreData.

If I have a MyManagedObject class which has been given 'mobjc' as name, then in profiler I can see an increasing number of:

> MyManagedObject_mobjc_

the number may vary, and for small amount of data, for example 100 objects in sqllite, it grows to that limit and stays there.

But it also seems that sometimes during the application lifecycle the objects are deallocated, so I suppose that CoreData itself is doing some kind of memory optimizations.
It also seems that not the whole object is retained, but rather the 'fault' of it (please forgive my english :-) ) because of the small live byte size.
Even tough a lot of fault objects would also occupy memory.

But at this point I would like some confirmation:

- is CoreData really managing and optimizing object in memory ?
- is there anything I can do for helping my application to retain less object as possible ?
- related to the point above, do I really need to take care of this issue or not ?
- do you have some link, possibly by Apple, where this specific subject is explained ?

maybe it is relevant, the app I used for testing rely on ARC and iOS 5.1.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this SO topic, [Core Data Memory Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734554/core-data-memory-management), you can find the info you are looking for.

This, instead, is the link to Apple doc on [Core Data Memory Managament](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMemory.html).

Few tips here.

First, when you deal with Core Data you deal with an object graph. To reduce memory consumption (*to prune your graph*) you can do a `reset` on the context you are using or turn objects into fauts passing `NO` to `refreshObject:(NSManagedObject *)object mergeChanges:(BOOL)flag` method. If you pass `NO` to that method, you can lose unsaved changes, so pay attention to it.

Furthermore, don't use Undo Management if you don't need it. It increases memory use (by default in iOS, no undo manager is created).

Hope that helps.